# Problem with an integral involving hypergeometric functions

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I want to evaluate the integral
\begin{align}
K=&\int\limits_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\:(1-z)^{-2\varepsilon}z^{-\varepsilon}
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\:(1-t)^{-1-\varepsilon}t^{-\varepsilon}
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\:(1-v)^{-1-\varepsilon}v^{-1-\varepsilon}\\
&F_{21}\left(1,1+\varepsilon;1-\varepsilon;\frac{zvt}{(1-v)(1-t)}\right)
\end{align}
where I leave $\varepsilon$ vague on purpose, because it comes from the context of dimensional regularization in Quantum Field Theory. Performing the $v$ integral was done in http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/4893/

with the result
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\:(1-v)^{-1-\varepsilon}v^{-1-\varepsilon}
F_{21}\left(1,1+\varepsilon;1-\varepsilon;\frac{zvt}{(1-v)(1-t)}\right)=
-\frac{2}{\varepsilon}\frac{\Gamma(1-\varepsilon)^2}{\Gamma(1-2\varepsilon)}F_{21}\left(1,-\varepsilon;1-\varepsilon;\frac{-zt}{1-t}\right)
\end{align}
For this they used the sum representation of $F_{21}$ and then swapped the sum and the integral. There is a divergence, when the argument of $F_{21}$ is equal to 1, but they show that this divergence is integrable, so swapping sum and integral works. I would like to use the same trick also for the $t$ integration. When I do this and then use Euler's integral transform to perform the integral over z, I end up with
\begin{align}
K=\frac{-2}{\varepsilon^2}\frac{\Gamma(1-\varepsilon)^5}{\Gamma(1-2\varepsilon)\Gamma(2-3\varepsilon)}F_{31}(1,-\varepsilon,1-\varepsilon;1+\varepsilon,2-3\varepsilon,1)
\end{align}
Is this the correct result or are there problems with swapping sum and integration while performing the $t$ integral?

EDIT: Maybe I should add, that I think this result is wrong, because it does not properly cancel another term in my calculation, which I think it should.